# How to implement custom camera preview in iOS?

Tags: swift4, xcode9

I am trying to implement Custom camera effect like:- [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKYzv.jpg)
I Thought that this is achieve like [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI1xS.jpg) 
This type of functionality already implemented in one app which is available in App Store. here is the link [enter link description here](https://itunes.apple.com/am/app/rageon/id1031607191?mt=8)
I want to copy this app's camera functionality.

I have already implemented something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJsYV.jpg).
I am using below code for achieved above functionality.
Into ViewController.swift class.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

 @available(iOS 10.0, *)
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
@IBOutlet weak var vc: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupCamera()
}
override  func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    session.startRunning()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    session.stopRunning()
}



 @IBOutlet fileprivate var previewView: PreviewView! {
didSet {
  previewView.videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
   previewView.layer.cornerRadius = previewView.layer.frame.size.width/2
    previewView.clipsToBounds = true

   }
  }

  @IBOutlet fileprivate var imageView: UIImageView! {
didSet {
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.layer.frame.size.width/2
  imageView.clipsToBounds = true
   }
 }

 fileprivate let session: AVCaptureSession = {
 let session = AVCaptureSession()
  session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
  return session
}()

 fileprivate let output = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()

}

   @available(iOS 10.0, *)
extension ViewController {

 func setupCamera() {
let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: 
 AVMediaTypeVideo)
guard let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera) else { 
 fatalError("back camera not functional.") }
session.addInput(input)
session.addOutput(output)
previewView.session = session

  }

  }


// MARK: - @IBActions
  @available(iOS 10.0, *)
   private extension ViewController {
    @IBAction func capturePhoto() {

  if let videoConnection = output.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {

    output.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: { (CMSampleBuffer, Error) in
        if let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(CMSampleBuffer) {

            if let cameraImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                self.imageView.image = cameraImage

                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(cameraImage, nil, nil, nil)
            }
        }
    })
}

}
 }
```

Also Create Preview Class and this class into UIView from storyboard file.
From above code I have achived [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuSUF.jpg).
I need to add any shape of image layer as a frame into UIView. ButI have no idea how to achieved this type of functionality. 
**So, Basically my task is, how to add any shape of image layer into UIView and after capture image how to save image with image layer, like** [Final Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26F2S.jpg)  [clue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MFG5.jpg)